Can we control the order of Cypress spec files in different folders during Parallel execution on Lambdatest?
cypress/e2e/orderCreation/*.cy.ts
cypress/e2e/commonActions/*.cy.ts

I have two different folders containing multiple spec files, In orderCreation folder I have spec files creating different type of orders and after creation I' storing orderId's in Json File.
Now In commonActions folder spec files, One of the spec file is dependent on orderCreation folder as this spec files using json data created by orderCreation spec files.
Here I'm using specs setting in Lambdatest.config.json file
"run_settings": {
    ...
    "parallels": 3,
    "specs": "cypress/e2e/orderCreation/*.cy.ts,cypress/e2e/commonActions/*.cy.ts",
    ...
  }

But it start executing spec files from both folder at same time, some files from orderCreation folder are pending and it's executing commonActions spec files.
Desired behaviour:
It should execute multiple spec files in parallel , but first execute all spec files of 'orderCreation' folder then move to commonActions folder spec files.

It is usually highly undesirable to have tests dependent on other tests. When a developer debugs a test locally by running a single test, it would be highly unexpected for it to fail just because another test has not been completed. It's very hard to reason about, and you can no longer take a test failure as being because that test in isolation has an issue. This is especially true if the things in commonActions actually mutate the "order" in some way. Every test needs its own fixture data, without interfering with stuff created in other tests.

What you have currently is like a false abstraction and I would strongly encourage you to rethink your testing strategy. If those tests need the other tests to run -- then you already have a fundamental issue. You can either remove that dependency (every test creates it own fixtures), or accept that this is actually 1 test falsely represented as many. Whilst you could find a way to "make these ones execute first", you are fixing the symptoms of a much bigger, deeper problem, without addressing it directly.

See https://www.cypress.io/blog/test-isolation-as-a-best-practice for a breakdown of this

@adsy you are right, And I had earlier developed the test cases which were independent from each other and after creating order I was performing mutual actions in second test case in same spec file. . . But the requirement came from my teamLead he want different spec file for common Actions, Which were working fine in sequential execution but in Lambdatest Parallel exection, Common Actions sepc file is being executed with order creation spec files on which it is dependent.

Not Sure about other parallel execution platforms like cypress dashboard/browserStack but in case of parallel execution, lambdatest doesn't support to execute any other spec file or folder of spec files in order/sequence. It can initiate any spec file in queue.
So for my scenario there are only two option.

Either Create order and modify order tests in one spec file
Second is to first create order and manually create a json file which will contain order_ids and then use this data file for modify orders spec file. In this case Modify spec file will not depend on create orders spec tests, and will have their own data to perform operation.


You would need to compose your tests by importing into a "runner" test, something like this:
context('orders workstream', () => {
  require('./create-order.cy.js')
  require('./modify-order.cy.js')
  require('./delete-order.cy.js')
})

From the sound of it you may have backed yourself into a corner with the structure of the tests.
A better strategy would be to run the order creation against the backend, to prove the full end-to-end path, then use fixtures and cy.intercept to show the rest of the front-end functionality is correct.
That way you are not dependent on an order id generated from the back end.
